# manifest unknown error adding psql under docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I make in docker php/postgres / phppgadmin  and I need to add psql to my project to upload my sql dumps.
I found this https://hub.docker.com/r/softwareplant/psql and added it to my project, but running build command I got error :

```
docker-compose up -d --build
... 
Sccessfully built 3b0700d7bed8
Successfully tagged lprodsdocker_web:latest
Pulling psql (softwareplant/psql:latest)...
ERROR: manifest for softwareplant/psql:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

My docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:

    web:
        build:
            context: ./web           # directory of web/Dockerfile.yml
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
            # - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data

        container_name: lprods_web

        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8086:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}



    db:
        image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
        container_name: lprods_db
        ports:
            - '5433:5432'
        restart: always
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '1'
            POSTGRES_DB: 'wprods'
        volumes:
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


    phppgadmin:
        image: dockage/phppgadmin:latest
        environment:
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST=db
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT=5432
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_DEFAULT_DB=postgres
        container_name: lprods_phppgadmin

        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8087:80
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - db

    psql:
        image: softwareplant/psql
        environment:
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST=db
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT=5432
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_DEFAULT_DB=postgres
        container_name: lprods_phppgadmin

        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8087:80
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - db

    composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        container_name: lprods_composer
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install  --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Which way is correct ? On https://hub.docker.com there is such image...
Is it invalid ?  Can you advice some other decision ?

**MODIFIED :**
Next I try

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/governmentpaas/psql
Provides psql Postgres client. 

description seems like what I need : to upload dump into postgres db
In docker-compose.yml I added item :

    psql:
        image: governmentpaas/psql
        environment:
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST=db
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT=5432
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_DEFAULT_DB=postgres
        container_name: lprods_psql

        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8088:80"
            - "444:444"
        links:
            - db
```

and it was installed ok and I see this container in hosting OS:

```
lprods_docker$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                                        NAMES
a3342c0b0df4        dockage/phppgadmin:latest   "/sbin/entrypoint ap"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                   0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8087->80/tcp   lprods_phppgadmin
3ffa2823257a        governmentpaas/psql         "/bin/sh"                16 minutes ago      Restarting (0) 42 seconds ago                                                lprods_psql
7071eaf067d6        lprodsdocker_web            "docker-php-entrypoi"   17 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                   0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp                         lprods_web
4372e269daf8        postgres:9.6.10-alpine      "docker-entrypoint.s"   17 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes                   0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp                       lprods_db
```

But entering bash container no psql command found :

```
# uname -a
Linux 7071eaf067d6 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@7071eaf067d6:/var/www/lprods_docker_root# whereis psql

# psql -v
bash: psql: command not found
```

Is it image I need ? If yes, how to use it ?

Comment: softwareplant/psql seem to be postgresql server why you need 2 database ?

Comment: looks like that is invalid package.
Working with posgtres I use command like 
 psql -h localhost  -d dbname -U  postgres  -W 
when I need to upload sql dump into dbname database. But in my web container I do not have psql coomand.
How to install it ?

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED block

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the tag of the image, e.g.:

```
version: '3'

services:

[...]

    psql:
        image: softwareplant/psql:dev-jira7

[...]
```